# jQuery File Download Plugin go always in fail function

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, download

I'm using this plugin to download file by jquery.
The problem is that i enter in fail function also when i download correctly the file. This is my code:

```
function openDownloadDialog(serialNumber) {
    //TODO gestire okButton per scaricare la chiave

    $.fileDownload("/async/paas/caaas/downloadCertificate/"+serialNumber)
    .done(function (url) { 
        $("#modalDownloadFailedCertificate").modal("hide");})
    .fail(function (responseHtml,url) {
        $("#modalDownloadFailedCertificate").modal("show");
    });
}
```

How can i resolve this problem?
thanks in advance

Comment: my web services /async/paas/caaas/downloadCertificate/ return true o false, what want FileDownload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved with cookie setting:

```
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");
```

else if i have an exception set so:

```
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=false; path=/");
```

Comment: For custom cookies, use addHeader instead of setHeader, because setHeader deletes all other "Set-Cookie" headers